# Only get invoice id and will only make use of it to retrieve invoice only

Tags: c#, stripe-payments, stripes

It is the case that I would very much like to get the invoice ID in the database or that I basically get the invoice url that I can throw in the database. Where the customer will be able to pick up the invoice.

I have found that it is after CREATING the invoice that I will first be able to download the urls that I will be able to use or when I have created it.

Basically, the mistake is that I have tried for several hours to find out how to retrieve the url for the invoice or that I just get the invoice url back that I want to be able to go through in the database.

```
var token = model.Source;

var trailDay = PricRules.PayUser.TrailDay;

var createCustomer = new CustomerCreateOptions
{
    Source = token,
    Email = userClass.Mail,
    Name = userClass.FullName,
    Description = $"UserId: {userClass.UserId} - CVR: {business.Cvr} - Navn: {business.Name} - TrailDay: {trailDay}"
};
var addService = new CustomerService();
var customer = await addService.CreateAsync(createCustomer);

var optionsProduct = new ProductCreateOptions
{
    Name = $"Medlemskab - Brugerid: {userClass.UserId}",
    Type = "service",
};
var serviceProduct = new ProductService();
Product product = serviceProduct.Create(optionsProduct);


var optionsPlan = new PlanCreateOptions
{
    Currency = "dkk",
    Interval = Stripe.interval,
    Nickname = $"Medlemskab - InterVal: {Stripe.interval} Name: {userClass.FullName} - {DateTime.Now}",
    Amount = amount,
    Product = product.Id,
    IntervalCount = getPriceClass.Month,
};
var servicePlan = new PlanService();
Plan plan = servicePlan.Create(optionsPlan);

var items = new List<SubscriptionItemOptions>()
{
    new SubscriptionItemOptions()
    {
        Plan = plan.Id
    }
};
var createSubscruption = new SubscriptionCreateOptions
{
    Customer = customer.Id,
    TrialEnd = new AnyOf<DateTime?, SubscriptionTrialEnd>(DateTime.Now.AddDays(trailDay)),
    Items = items,
    OffSession = true
};
var Addservice = new SubscriptionService();
Subscription subscription = Addservice.Create(createSubscruption);

var invoiceLink = ""; // HOW TO GET INVOICE URL/LINK HER? or Invoice Id
```

As you can see here at the bottom of code. So it basically does not matter if I get the invoice id or if it is the url. I am aware of how I make use of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't get an invoice link straight away, because it's dependent on an attempt to take a payment first.

You should setup a webhook to listen for [`invoice.created`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-invoice.created) events. Each event will contain an [`invoice`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object) object, from which you can access the customer's id, the subscription id, and a link to the invoice, thus giving you enough information to link the invoice back to the correct customer.

Comment: Okay, that gives me a part that I want to be able to work on and think about how I just got it done. But it's nice that you just give some information that I will take with you to read about webhook Thanks!